# API keys for a Firebase project transferred to another project on Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, api, cloud

I was looking at my API keys on Google Cloud for one of my Firebase projects and as I switched between different projects, I saw that it is now listed under another Firebase project of mine. I never initiated this change (this happened while browsing through my Google Cloud projects). I am suspecting that this may be a temporary error but I cannot be sure. Does anyone know why this happened and how I can get it back to the correct project?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds *very* unlikely, but there definitely nothing anyone here can do about it. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: It does sound unlikely but the dates of the keys together with the dates of the auto-generated Firebase keys prove this (project was created in 2020, the keys that were moved were created in 2014)... I have submitted a bug report to Firebase. Thanks for suggesting that.